# Limit of sequence of fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given sequence $a_n = (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2})$. How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 0$ and $a_n$ is not increasing?

Comment: For non-increasing, consider $a_{n+1}-a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{2n+2}\frac1{(n+1)^2+i}-\frac 1{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

If we approximate the sum by an integral centered on each term we have $$a_n \approx \int_{{n+\frac 12}}^{{(n+1)^2+\frac 12}}\frac {dx}x
\\ \approx \log ((n+1)^2+\frac 12)-\log (n+\frac 12)
\\ \approx \log (n+1)$$ which is neither decreasing nor of limit $0$

Comment: I have another idea: $    \frac{n^2}{2^{2 log_2(n+1)}} < a_n < \frac{n^2}{2^{log_2(n+1)}} $. What do you think about it?

Comment: @alex:  That is just $\frac {n^2}{(n+1)^2} \lt a_n \lt \frac {n^2}{n+1}$  While true, the bounds are not very tight.  The left side is just below $1$, which shows $a_n$ doesn't go to zero.  The right side is much larger than $a_n$

Answer (score 0):

An other approach maybe , but your sequence does not $\rightarrow 0$:

Let: $ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} $ the partial harmonic sum.

As is well known : $H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + o(1)$

Now: $ a_n = H_{(n+1)^2} - H_n = (\ln((n+1)^2) + \gamma + o(1)) - (\ln(n) + \gamma + o(1)) $

$\implies a_n = \ln(n+1) + ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) + o(1) = \ln(n+1) + o(1) $

Hence, ($a_n$) is actually $\rightarrow +\infty$

Answer (score 0):

The simple lower bounding
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\ge
\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n}\ge\frac{n}{2n}=\frac12
$$
proves that $a_n\not\to 0$.